# Remove devstack dependencies Ununtu 14.04 (32 Bit Dell Lattitude 5500)

Tags: ubuntu, kvm, openstack

I installed `devstack` in my old laptop.

After installation when I try to access `OpenStack`, my laptop became very slow. Then I realized, that laptop had only 2 GB RAM.

I ran `unstack.sh` and delete `devstack` folder (with virtualenv).

Next day, when I start my laptop again, it was just flashing lights on keyboard and was not able to start.

I tried to see log by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> when start booting, and I figured out, it was giving error for some KVM execution and stopped working.

[image: KVM Error]

I want to know that, is there any way to remove all dependency installed by `devstack`?

Comment: look in `/var/log/dpkg.log` for packages installed around the time you installed devstack.

Comment: @cas, I checked `/var/log/dpkg.log` but there is no error in it.

Comment: I didn't say to check for an error, I said to look for the packages installed around the same time you installed devstack.  The implication is obvious: you can uninstall those packages.

Comment: @cas I updated question with screenshot. Can you please check, why its failing ?